# How to remove the NBA player's position from the dataframe and create a new column 'Position'?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

I am still learning Python and would love some help if possible. So far I have scraped the NBA player NAMES but the player POSITION is attached to the data.

I have two goals that I would like to accomplish with your help:

1. Remove the player Position from the Name data
2. Create a new column for the player Position named 'Position'

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/lal/season/2020/seasontype/2'
df = pd.read_html(url)

playerNames = df[0]

#edit to eliminate the '*' in the playerNames
playerNames['Name'] = playerNames['Name'].str.replace('*','')
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
Name

Anthony Davis PF

Lebron James SF

Kyle Kuzma SF

...
```

Here is my desired output:

```
Name                Position

Anthony Davis          PF

Lebron James           SF

Kyle Kuzma             SF
...
```

I have looked online to find which method is best and I have seen the following methods: strip, replace, remove, regex, etc. I have yet to come across an example that strips all of the data after the 2nd space. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer. =)

Also, I would prefer not to use regex if possible. I have not started learning this method yet since it seems rather confusing and a little sloppy. If that is the only way than I will still be grateful. Thanks!

Here is the updated code... Still in progress:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/lal/season/2020/seasontype/2'
df = pd.read_html(url)

playerNames = df[0]

playerNames['Position'] = playerNames['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
playerNames['Position'] = playerNames['Name'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
playerNames['Position'] = playerNames['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
playerNames['Name'] = playerNames['Name'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()[:-1]))
```

Comment: I tried adding this code to mine but did not see the desired output. Perhaps I am doing it wrong. I was looking for 2 columns: player's name ('Name') and player's position ('Position'). Thanks for trying to help @ssnk001. Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Comment: Oh, yeah just change 'df' to 'playerNames' in my answer from above.

Comment: So change both df['Position'] and df['Name']? Any way you can show all of the code. Sorry, I am a little confused. I tried changing both of the dfs... I will keep messing with it. Thanks for your help so far. I apologize for not understanding. I see multiple dfs... didn't know if I was supposed to change all of the dfs to playerNames.

Comment: Just check the edit I made to the original answer. You're not changing multiple dfs, both those lines are making updates to the same df. the pd.read_html function is returning a list of dataframes not a dataframe, and you're selecting the first one with playerNames[0]. You should probably name this something other than df because it's not actually a dataframe, it's a list. playerNames is a dataframe. The first line is just creating a new column in the playerNames dataframe called position. You're doing this by splitting each item in original column by a delimiter and keeping the last element.

Comment: Ty sir for explaining this to me. I will work on the adjustments tonight and will spend more time on it this week if I don't have immediate success. This is still a learning process for me. Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me. Much appreciated. =)

Comment: I updated the code toward the bottom of my question. The new code you suggested did create a new column 'Postion' like you stated. Unfortunately it is double printing the player's Names in both the column 'Name' and the column 'Position'. Again, I could be doing something wrong. I will keep working on it. Thanks for you help.

Comment: check the edit, I had written the wrong column name, my bad.

Comment: Beautiful! =) Thank you so much for your time and patience. I can't thank you enough sir @ssnk001!